# Django: ModelMultipleChoiceField display description vs object

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to show ModelMultipleChoiceFields as CheckboxSelectMultiple. Right now it does render the checkboxes, but with the objects. I'd like to show the object description so the user knows what they are selecting.

How do I iterate over the foodstyles to pull that data? This is what I tried so far but that is throwing a TemplateSyntaxError."Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'generator' object has no attribute 'all'"

```
foodstyles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    label=_("Types of food you like"),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=FoodStyle.objects.all(),
    required=True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    foodstyles = FoodStyle.objects.all()
    self.fields['foodstyles'].queryset = (
        (r.description) for r in foodstyles)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to implement **unicode**(self) on your Model object, and return whatever string you want to be displayed in the form.